# Block mode for the eraser in Photoshop cc 2017

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixels, eraser

How do I enable the block mode for the eraser in Photoshop cc 2017?

Here is my program view:

[image]

I suppose the block mode should be somewhere in a Brush menu, but I can not find it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Window" menu, choose "Options". It will show a "Mode" dropdown where you can choose "Block":

[image]

Comment: You made my day! Thanks a lot for the help! Love you!

Comment: You're welcome :) Note that the tool options menu is useful for *many* of the tools and is shown by default - I guess it got hidden accidentally.